# shape of profile picture

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to change my the shape of my Profile picture in `moderncv` CV, style `classic`. Unfortunately I can not do it because the picture define in a box and my LaTeX knowledge is not good enough to understand it and change it.
I will appreciate an help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch thank you I am beginner in latex

Comment: You can try changing the 1st optional argument in the command `\photo`. That is instead of `\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}`, you can write `\photo[124pt][0.4pt]{picture}`.